# After `telnet`ing to a device, can not see the device prompt

Tags: networking, router, telnet

I have a virtual router on a server and I have assigned a port no - 20171 to a serial port

And I connect to this device using the cmd -
`telnet 10.X.Y.Z 20171`

And after that I see something like this -

```
Trying 10.X.Y.Z...
Connected to 10.X.Y.Z.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

indicating that telnet session is successfully established.

But after that I don't see any console prints from the router. Neither the `Router` prompt.
What could be the issue?

Note: If I change the serial port number to another port say 20172, then I see some logs.

I'm using bash running on RHEL as a telnet client

Comment: What client are you using exactly?  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: I'm using bash running on RHEL as a telnet client

Comment: You make no mention of that fact in your question body.

Comment: Okay. I didn't think that client would make a difference here. Anyways I've updated that information in the question now

Comment: Why not just leave it on port 20172? According to the information you provided, It seems like there is some conflict, obvious or not, with port 20171.

Answer (score 0):

Found that the ova which was deployed was not supporting the serial port.
Deployed a different ova with the support of serial port. It started work properly now.